# ClickOnce installing my database file on a different folder than my .exe?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, clickonce

I'm making an app that has a .mdb database file whose Build Action is Content and Copy to Output Directory is set to Always, but when I published it and tried to run it, the app couldn't find the database file. I checked where my app was installed and I found the .exe file in a folder called "sdre..tion_cbcedce3d840a9cc_0003.0000_e68ab34059956c01" and the database (together with an icon) in a folder called "sdre...exe_cbcedce3d840a9cc_0003.0000_none_02c3ca064ef1724b". Any idea why is this happening? I want the database to be on the same folder than the exe. I did this the same way before and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Hi
Can you just confirm, was the connection string set up through the Add Data source wizzard and if so did you tell it to create a local copy?

I tend to use SetUp projects to release my apps as this gives direct control over where the project outputs are sent